# How do I create a role with access to all collections in a database?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, I want to create a role with read/write access to all collections in a database,  how would I do that? I'm using

```
db.createRole({
     role: "rolenamehere",
     privileges: [
        {
          resource: {
            role: 'readWrite',
            db: 'dbnamehere'
          }, actions: ["find"]
        }
     ],
     roles: []
})
```

to create a role, but it gives me the error
`MongoServerError: resource must set both db and collection or neither, but not exactly one.`

Am I able to specify all collections, or do I have to add each collection to it manually?

Comment: That's in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.1/reference/resource-document/#specify-a-database-as-resource)

Answer (score 3):

Specify `resource` document with both `db` and `collection`. If you want to apply the privilege to all collections, the give empty string as - `{ db: "test", collection: "" }`

Refer - [Specify a database as resource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/resource-document/#specify-a-database-as-resource)